# What is the KMS road warrior user experience?

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, kms, microsoft-office-2013

We provide Office and Exchange and Sharepoint services to our users who are all "permanent road warriors" - by which I mean they don't belong to any domain, they don't even dial in to a VPN, they act as if they were using hosted services.

We are about to purchase Office 2013 and would like to move to a KMS licencing setup for Office. I understand they will need to VPN in to our network to connect to the KMS server (Server 2012) every now and then, which is OK. They will only ever VPN in for this reason. My question is about what the experience will be for them.

I understand a computer can go 180 days without connecting to the KMS. But I see mentions of 30 days in places. Will the users recieve alerts or anything? My desire is that after 180 they recieve an alert, VPN in, validate the licence and then get on with things. I don't want them being continually notified that there were errors connecting the the KMS or something.

So the question is: **As an Office 2013 user, what do you experience if your computer can't connect to the KMS server? After a week, after a month, after 180 days....** Also, what happens if your computer can't connect to the KMS at the moment of installation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: @SvW I don't see how these are related at all.

Comment: @SvW I don't feel that this question is related to software licencing in the way that the "duplicate question" is. I'm not asking you how many licences to buy, which licences, etc. I'm asking a technical question about what actually happens on a desktop over time if it can't connect to a KMS server. This is not related to the issues covered on the "duplicate question". Perhaps I should have asked this on SuperUser, I'll give you that much :-).